# indefinite article with 'school'

Tags: indefinite-article

Could you explain why is there used indefinite article before ***school***, when the context is about **institution** rather than **building** of (a?) school.

> For most children, secondary education begins when they enter **a** comprehensive school or **a** more traditional grammar school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either one is correct:

> - For most children, education begins when they enter comprehensive school or traditional grammar school.
> - For most children, education begins when they enter **a** comprehensive school or **a** traditional grammar school.

They are almost completely equivalent.

Having the word "a" there **might** remind the reader (or suggest) that there was a choice of *different* comprehensive schools or *different* traditional grammar schools, from which one was selected.   But this is secondary to the main point of the sentence.

This meaning, or *sense* of the word *a* is not certain -- it is one possible interpretation -- so you can consider this to be **ambiguous**, and you can consider the two choices to be exactly the same.